# Opening different web pages in a control/block/panel/plugin on the same page

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, sharepoint-2010, content-editor

I need to develop a page where there would be a list of links on left and clicking on a particular link opens a web page in a control/block/panel/plugin/etc but on the same page. The idea is to open different web pages but on the same page in a control/block/panel/plugin/etc. How can I achieve this? Client needs this solution in SharePoint 2010 portal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it what I was looking for. The solution I found has been implemented in jQuery. I was looking for a vertical menu instead of the horizontal as given in the solution but never mind we can change it any time. In this jQuery solution the content loads dynamically in a jQuery panel. All your content goes into a  element. You can even dynamically load PDF document wrapped in a  element inside the  element.

I implemented this solution in SharePoint 2010 using a Content Editor web part and it worked like I expected. Kudos to the developer team of this awesome solution.

To download the solution: https://github.com/cheynewallace/jquery-content-panel-switcher

DEMO: http://www.cheynewallace.com/demo/jcps/single_demo.html